# form action lost after PostBack vb.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hi I have a page called campaign_accept_reject.aspx:

When the page first loads the form renders as the below:

```
<form method="post" action="./campaign_accept_reject.aspx?EmailTo=me@myemail.com" id="AcceptForm">
```

In this page I have an submit button `<input type="image" name="emailBtn" id="emailBtn">` Which calls on the following event:

```
Protected Sub emailBtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Handles emailBtn.Click
```

So far so good apart from the fact that after I click the emailBtn the form action is lost and it renders as form method="post" action="data:;" id="AcceptForm" which stops me from raising the emailBtn.Click event again and it goes to a blank page.

Does anybody know what's happening or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: remove the action tag if you added it manually and change the button to submit instead of image

Comment: Update! After having gone through Firebug it looks like Chrome is blocking the request. The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in 'http://localhost:52252/accept_reject.aspx? because its source code was found within the request. The auditor was enabled as the server sent neither an 'X-XSS-Protection' nor 'Content-Security-Policy' header. This problem does not occur on Firefox and Edge. Anybody know how to fix this in Chrome programmatically?

Comment: OK I have fixed this by adding the following header   Response.AppendHeader("X-XSS-Protection", "0") Not sure how safe it is do do that so if you have a better solution please let me know. Thank you.